# Software used for this slideshow/animation?

Tags: animation

could someone please tell me what software could have been used to create this slideshow/animation? Could they have used a template?

http://media.boxstudios.com/17096_art_na_stills_paper_29_12_b_web_mp4_3ip.mp4

Answer (score 1):

**Software you could do that effect with**:

- Adobe After Effects
- Blackmagic Fusion
- Nuke
- Autodesk Toxik
- Autodesk Flame
- Autodesk Smoke
- Adobe Premiere Pro
- Apple Final Cut Pro and Final Cut X
- Avid Media Composer
- Avid Symphony
- Corel video Studio
- Magix Movie Edit Pro
- Lightworks
- Sony Vegas
- Natron
- KDEnlive
- Avisynth
- Cinelerra
- Pitivi
- FFMPEG (given enough time)
- Blender
- Lightwave
- 3D studio Max
- Autodesk Maya
- Cinema 4d
- Photoshop (yes, really)
- the Gimp (ditto)
- Processing (if you're handy with java)
- OpenFrameworks (ditto, but C++)
- many more… Pretty much any [compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Compositing_software), visual effects or 3D animation application, and most [NLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_editing_software)s could do it

**Could they have used a template**: yes.